# Erro Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'

Tags: sql-server

Esse código gera o seguinte erro:

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure totalGastoPedido, Line 7 Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.totalGastoPedido(@id_mesa int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
       DECLARE @Total money
       SET @Total = (SELECT SUM(ped.ValorPagar))
       FROM Pedido ped
       where @id_mesa = IdMesa
       and ped.Data>'2016-02-10' and ped.Data<'2016-02-10'   

    RETURN @Total
END
```

Comment: Podes explicar melhor a pergunta? Qual é o problema, qual é o erro? O que estás a tentar fazer?

Comment: Isso aí é no sql server?

Comment: Peço desculpa que não escrevi completo, Eu pretendo fazer uma Function que receba o Id da mesa e retorne o total gasto daquela mesa
 num determinado período

Comment: E sim é SQL SERVER, sou begginer em sql server

Comment: Quando tendo compilar o erro aparece no FROM

Comment: Edita a pergunta, colca a mensagem do erro, tag do sql server tbm.

Comment: Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure totalGastoPedido, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'FROM'.

Comment: @Alexandru podes [edit] a pergunta e juntar essas informações?

Answer (score 1):

Seu select esta com um erro de sintaxes, quando você faz um select para setar o valor do select em alguma variável `( SET @Total =)` , você precisa envolver todo o select entre parenteses  `SET @Total = (select campo from tabela)`, no seu caso você esta  fechando o parentese antes do **from** `(SELECT SUM(ped.ValorPagar))`, esse ultimo parentese tem que ser removido e inserido no final do select.

```
create FUNCTION dbo.totalGastoPedido(@id_mesa int)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN  

DECLARE @Total money

 declare @Pedido table
       (
         IdMesa int,
         ValorPagar numeric(18,2)
       )

       insert into @Pedido values
       (1,122.32),
       (1,12.32),
       (1,2.32),
       (4,1.32),
       (5,2.32)

       SET @Total = (SELECT SUM(ped.ValorPagar) -- removar o parenteses daqui e coloque no final da query
       FROM @Pedido ped
       where @id_mesa = IdMesa
       --and ped.Data>'2016-02-10' and ped.Data<'2016-02-10' --- comentado para facilita na buscar
       ) -- Aqui....

    RETURN @Total
END
```

Comment: Muito Obrigado, Marco, Eu descobri ontem o erro, Abraço